# grep first and sirnames from free text forms

Tags: mysql, perl

Has anyone ever seen a good attempt of splitting strings for single or multiple names?
To make an example :
Users are able to bring in their names into an Form, unfortunately it goes from **`John J. Johnson`** (easy), **`John/Peter Johnson`** (2 Persons) up to **`Michael Peter John Paul`** or **`Stacy Miller Kevin Mitnick`**.
So far I have built a database with first and lastnames, which I check against. But I wonder if someone really has made an attempt to do this properly with a high hit ratio.

Comments much appreciated. Thx

Comment: Can't you provide two cells to input first and last names separately?

Comment: Nope, i get these datas from third parties. To be exact travel industry and i can tell you people are very "creative" when it comes to describe who and how much people are coming into a hotel perfect example :

"Mike + Ute SCHROBSDORFF / FABER" the f**k is that supposed to be

Comment: I would say that this is impossible. For example someone changed their name to ["Trout fishing in America"](http://google.com/search?q="trout+fishing+in+america"+name+change+Peter+Eastman) [wikipedia.com](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trout_Fishing_in_America) [manolith.com](http://www.manolith.com/2009/10/21/the-10-stupidest-things-people-have-changed-their-names-to/) [snopes.com](http://www.snopes.com/racial/language/names.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The nearest I've ever seen to that is [Lingua::EN::NamedEntity](https://metacpan.org/release/Lingua-EN-NamedEntity), but it's a hard problem to solve. It's probably impossible to get a perfect solution, but you might get something that works in your case.

Comment: Thank you. I think it will be pretty much impossible especially taking into account that this is supposed to work with names from all over the world and the fact that there seem to be people in china that name their child "@".